# Access parameter passed through custom protocol through .reg file

Tags: windows, shell, registry, protocols

I am currently trying to make enable making calls from our intranet software directly through dialer.exe.

I have prepared this registry script and added it to the local registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip]
@="URL:Telephone Dialer"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dialer.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dialer.exe\" \"%1\""
```

When a link with the following protocoll: sip:123456 gets called the registry realizes that its connected with the dialer exe. Unfortunately I can't access the passed throuhg value which would be necessary to have in the dialer.exe input field in order to just press "Dial" and call the number.

What should I do different here?

Comment: Use a 3rd party tool, dialer.exe does not support a command line.

Comment: a 3rd party tool for what? Passing some value? Or a 3rd party tool instead of dialer exe? What 3rd party tool would you suggest? Could you be more precise?

Comment: you need to find a 3rd party SIP dialler that accepts a phone number as a command line or perhaps this http://www.atrandom.iansharpe.com/phone-dial.php

Comment: According to msdn dialer.exe can be executed with an additional parameter like so: "PATH\dialer.exe" "123456" -> so I could create an executeable file that gets the phone number as parameter through my registry and then opens the exe with given parameter. Or not?

Comment: If I run `C:\>c:\Windows\System32\dialer.exe "447123456789"` the dial box is not populated with anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
The following steps need to be done:

Step1: Download the Beta software from [here](http://www.atrandom.iansharpe.com/phone-dial.php)

Step2: Extract the Dial.exe into ..\Program Files\Dial\

Step3: Create a new registry entry as following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip]
"EditFlags"=hex:02,00,00,00
@="URL:Sip Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Dial\\Dial.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Step4: Save it as .reg and execute the file.

Step5: Check if \Windows\System32\ contains the following file: `msvcr100.dll`

IF it doesn't, paste in the file from the zip folder.

If it does then it's done.

Now you only need to take care, that the number you want to dial starts with `sip:` Example: `<a href="sip:1234567">Dial</a>`